# Красивая анимация для больших элементов макета

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, reactjs, meteor

Здравствуйте!

Очень волнует вопрос, с помощью каких технологий (библиотеки, фреймворки) можно реализовать анимацию на сайте? Я имею в виду не fade-in/fade-out для маленьких элементов страницы, а анимацию для больших элементов сайта.

В интернете много примеров, но под рукой оказался [один](http://atmospherejs.com): когда нажимаем на значок меню в левом верхнем углу, то весь текущий макет уменьшается и смещается вправо на половину экрана, оставшуюся половину экрана занимает появившийся список разделов. Меня это очень впечатлило, как реализовать, кто может поделиться наводками?

П.С. Нашел очень скудную информацию про [famo.us](http://famous.org), про него кто-то знает/пользовался? Как я понял, проект умер год назад.

П.П.С. Сам разрабатываю (пытаюсь) на Метеоре, в качестве ui-фреймворка использую reactjs, если вдруг найдутся разработчики, которые знают решения для анимации совместимые с этими технологиями, буду рад вдвойне!

Буду очень признателен за ответы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: копайте в сторону css transition и css transform, вот тут анимация сделана на CSS: https://atmospherejs.com/ Не без помощи javascript, но javascript обычно простой и нужен только для добавления класса по клику или другому событию, чтобы вся анимация начала работать.

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо вам за ответ! Вы отите сказать, что приведённый пример на этом сайте сделан с помощью css? Там это работает настолько плавно, замедляется к концу движения, что в это трудно поверить.

Comment: нелийнейная анимация это тоже довольно таки просто, вот основные её виды: http://easings.net/

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать [GSAP (GreenSock Animation Platform)](http://greensock.com/gsap) - одна из лучших библиотек для создания комплексного интерактива на сайте.
Ребята из [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/), часто используют [dynamics.js](http://dynamicsjs.com/). Я не использовал, но возможно она вам понравится.
[Список библиотек для анимации](https://github.com/moklick/frontend-stuff#animations).

Касательно указанного примера с меню, то конкретно такая анимация сделана на чистом `css` (только переключение состояния происходит на `js`), весьма вероятно вручную, без использования плагинов.

Если анимация на сайте комплексная, если нужно контролировать время и очередность появления анимаций - используйте `js` библиотеку.
Если анимация не очень большая, то можно описать самому через `css`. 
Авторы данного примера, посчитали что такая анимация не особо сложная, и решили сделать всё сами - уменьшение окна с контентом, плавное появление меню и т.д.